# Running Migration after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am trying to learn deployment using capistrano. I want to deploy the code on a separate folder in my local machine and run migrations after deployment. 
The capistrano gems used in the project are as follows

```
capistrano (3.4.0)
capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
capistrano-rails (1.1.3)
```

The application is using ruby 2.1 and rails 4.1
The deploy file is as follows

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'capistrano_study'
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/capistrano_study.git'

# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"
set :user, "prajeesh"
after "deploy:updated", "deploy:migrate"
namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

staging.rb file as follows.

```
server 'xx.x.x.xxx', user: 'prajeesh', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
set :deploy_to, "/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/capistrano_staging"
```

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: cap_test_staging
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxxx
#  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock




staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: cap_test_staging
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxxx
```

When i run the command **cap staging:deploy**, the deployment is working fine. The issue is that the migrations are not running after deployment.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:

This is the error that i am getting.

```
INFO [175f4b0b] Running /usr/bin/env rake db:migrate as 

prajeesh@xx.x.x.xxx
DEBUG [175f4b0b] Command: cd /home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/capistrano_staging/current && ( RAILS_ENV=development /usr/bin/env rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [175f4b0b]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [175f4b0b]    

cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
```

If i run the command RAILS_ENV=development /usr/bin/env rake db:migrate  directly from the project path, the migration is running but through capistrano it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should run the below command to get it run command:

```
cap deploy:migrate
```

To get it run, you can see the [documentation](https://github.com/capistrano/rails#capistranorails) here

**Updated for automating migration:**

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
```

Into the file `config/deploy.rb.`

Comment: Does that mean that i cannot automate this?

PS: i ran the command cap staging:deploy -- trace
The output is as follows
* Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:migrate

Still the table is not updated

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: as you can see in my original post, i am already using this.

after "deploy:updated", "deploy:migrate"

Answer (score 0):

You should require `capistrano/rails/migrations` in your Capfile as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/#usage). It'll do the trick.

Comment: I said add it to the Capfile, not deploy file.

Comment: I added the line that you mentioned. Now i am getting the following error.

rake stderr: rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Comment: As this is  part of a learning process, i am trying to deploy it on a separate folder in the local machine.  To make it clear, consider that I have a folder named prj1. This folder contains the deploy script which tries to deploy the code on a separate folder in the same machine. So i ran the deploy script from the project path of 'prj1' . Then i got the above mentioned error.

Comment: Check if you have latest bundler accessible from the directory you are deploying to. Also check if GEM_PATH is leading to correct Ruby version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Capistrano 3, I did

`set :migration_role, :app` in addition to adding `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` to my `deploy.rb` file.

(source: [capistrano-rails docs](https://github.com/capistrano/rails))